# Router behind router

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, wireless-networking

To extend my wireless upstairs I salvaged a second router and have been trying to set it up so that:

- SSID matches with primary router
- Password matches with primary router

Secondary router: Dlink DIR-615 (Hardware revision H2, Firmware 8.04 iirc)

Primary router is from ISP: Telenet. I only get basic ability to configure it.
According to the web gui my ISP provides:

- LAN-Subnet: 192.168.0.1
- LAN-Subnet IPv6 : 2a02:1812:1622:6400::/64

According to a forum user online: The DHCP range of the primary router is 192.168.X.[100-254]

How would I go for setting up the secondary router as an Access Point?

Am I forced to disable it's DHCP capabilities? Or can I change it's DHCP range to not match the primary router's DHCP range?

PS: Does having the second router also do DHCP, have any benefit on speed/capabilities?

Thank you for your help. If any further information is needed, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I forced to disable it's DHCP capabilities?

Yes.

Different routers have different setup, but the simplest way is to disable DHCP server on the second router. Plug the cable LAN to LAN (not LAN to WAN). Set the same SSID (but use different channel).

Answer (score 0):

Router 1: Telenet Router

Router 2: D-Link Router

What I understand you want to do is to Repeat or Extend the range of your existing wireless lan.
(see mode 4 http://www.ezlan.net/Wireless_Modes.html)

To do this your router 2 must have ability to put itself in Repeater/Range Extended mode. This will let the router 2 work as a client and AP at the same time.

In summary:

1. Broadcast the **same SSID** as your router 1
2. Forward the authentication protocol **to** your router 1
3. Forward the DHCP settings **from** router 1

I don't think you can set the router in repeater mode with the default firmware so you would need to flash the DD-WRT firmware.

CAREFULLY READ 
https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Installation

I personally recommend to pull a cable upstairs because of the 50% speed loss...

### EDIT 1

In case you are using the cable as you explained, I don't think this is possible with Telenet routers to Bridge 2 networks. In that case both devices must support to bridge network 1 with network 2. Which is not the case for both devices out of the box.

**Conclusion:**
If you want to Keep same SSID and Password by extending by cable its not possible with current setup. You will have to setup 2 different networks (see alternative).

Alternative:
You have 2 different networks topology as follow

```
+ Router 1 (WAN x.x.x.x) (LAN + DHCP Server 192.168.0.1) 
- Client 1 (LAN DHCP Client 192.168.0.100)
- Client 2 (LAN DHCP Client 192.168.0.101)
+ Router 2 (WAN DHCP Client 192.168.0.102) (LAN + DHCP Server 192.168.22.1) 
    - Client 3 (LAN DHCP Client 192.168.22.101)
    - Client 4 (LAN DHCP Client 192.168.22.102)
```

Best Regards,
Glenn

Comment: Download Firmware:
https://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database

Configure Repeater:
https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Universal_Wireless_Repeater

Comment: I already have a cable running to the place where the second router has to come. My question was if I could hook that router up with DHCP still enabled but in a different range then what my Telenet router's DHCP is using. Main goal was to expand the network. @Glenn G

Comment: Do merge 2 networks into 1 you have to bridge the devices, which Telenet Motorola routers do not support.